# Java and javac not recognized as internal or external commands

Tags: java, variables, installation, environment

I installed java and originally the java command worked but not javac. So I made a JAVA_HOME variable in environment viarables and added %JAVA_HOME%\bin; to the path variable. Now neither java nor javac work. It is worth nothing that I created a JAVA_HOME variable and added it incorrectly to path before this. I deleted this variable and erased it from path before starting over. However after I erased it the java command had already stopped working. Please help. Thank you.

Comment: Just make sure your PATH is correct; that's all it really needs.

Answer (score 0):

For java and javac to be recognized you need to set your environment variables JAVA_HOME and PATH.

JAVA_HOME should contain the path to the java installation folder.
For PATH you should add %JAVA_HOME%\bin

Comment: That is what I did. For some reason it made it worse.

Comment: What do you mean by 'made it worse'?

Comment: So I installed java and the command java worked but not javac. So I made the JAVA_HOME variable and placed it in the path. Now neither command work. Even after I remove JAVA_HOME from path and delete it as a variable.